# Airflow celery worker keeps trying to run completed tasks

Tags: python, celery, airflow

I recently added a new machine to my Airflow celery cluster (one that is listening on a separate queue).

Everything seemed to be running fine BUT the new worker keeps picking up the same couple of (completed) tasks over and over again. This is invisible from the airflow web interface, which just shows the old tasks as complete and no new tasks being picked up by the worker.

Checking the old task logs gives me messages like the following:

```
[2018-04-15 04:13:15,374] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: 
[2018-04-15 04:13:15,373] {models.py:1120} INFO - Dependencies not met 
for <TaskInstance: my_task 2018-04-13 03:05:00 [success]>, dependency 
'Task Instance State' FAILED: Task is in the 'success' state which is 
not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to 
be run.
```

over and over again

I've checked the metadata database and the tasks do show up as 'done'. I've tried restarting Celery, the scheduler, the worker and the servers themselves to no avail. Both the worker and the scheduler are running on UTC timezone as intended.

setup info:

- EC2 cluster on AWS
- MySQL Celery backend
- Airflow 1.8.0

Has anyone ever run into anything like this?

Comment: The defined value for the state is (uppercase) `'SUCCESS'`. Maybe the lowercase value is responsible for the trouble.

Comment: It's uppercase in the celery metadata, but it's lowercase in the application metadata. Just checked both databases and it's correct.

Comment: Also I have several working instances running on the same backend, I don't know why _this_ one isn't playing ball.

Comment: Nothing so far - tried fresh reinstalls of RabbitMQ, Celery, Airflow (both 1.8 and 1.9), the entire Python virtual environment. I think I'm just going to give up on this instance altogether and create a mirror of one of the previously working instances.